# UnRouted Net Constraint in Altium after Via Stitching

Tags: altium, layout, via, drc

I am just wrapping up my `Design` of one of my project in `Altium 17`. I was done with adding `Polygon Pour` for various nets. I was trying to add `Via Stitching` in Altium.

After adding the stitching, Altium `Design Rule Check` shows an error. See the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

It has been showing multiple of these errors. The nets and vias are actually connected with copper. I remember facing these problems earlier but I don't remember how I get sway with them. May I tried removing specific vias after Via Stitching and it solved the problem in the past but It is not helping me now.

I tried the suggestion in this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365410/altium-unrouted-net-in-fill) by disabling the "Check for incomplete connection" option and it solved the issue but I want to enable the option for detecting real issues.

Please help.

Comment: Are the stitching vias net-connected to the copper net i.e. have you set this up properly?

Comment: Yes. I have set them properly.